# Does a p12 file has important information?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, p12, phonegap

For a phonegap project I had to send p12 file and a provisioning profile file to a dev.
The guy did not work well and canceled the project.

I don't know exactly what is in these files, should I change my pass or everything is encrypted ?

thank you

Comment: You should revoke your certificates immediately

Comment: Done. Thank you very much